# How the for loop works in this case?

Tags: verilog

As title. I'm quite unsure how the for loop would help to count the number of 1's in the input.

```
always @(*)
     begin 
        for ( int i= 0 ;i< 255 ;i++ )
        out = out + in[i];
     end
```

If my input is 1001, out = out + in[1001]. So how can it count the number of 1's in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input `in` is defined something like `input [254:0] in` then you would never have `in[1001]` as `in` is indexed on `i` that goes from 0 to 254.

As long as `out` is at least 8 bits, this should calculate the number of 1s in the input though not very efficiently for hardware as it's describing a long chain of 1-bit adders starting from `in[0] + out` to `in[254] + out` where the output of the previous adder is fed into the next. There is also an error as you need to initialize `out` to 0 or your loop will run forever as the `always` block depends on both `in` and `out` in its current implementation.

Comment: If compiler supports SV then one can try using `$bits(in)` to decide the depth of the `for` loop and `always@(in)` should avoid the forever loop issue.

Comment: Yes, though I would caution against explicit sensitivity lists like `always @(in)` as you are likely to forget to add a dependent variable at some point. Also, doing so in this case would create a latch on `out` as it would attempt to use the last value of `out` instead of 0 if `in` changes.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is it doesn't initialize `out`. Without resetting `out` to zero, any change to `in` will only increment `out`; potentially overflow and keep adding.

The question is tagged as Verilog, but it is using SystemVerilog syntax. There proper Verilog way of writing this code would be:

```
integer i; // 'int' is a SystemVerilog keyword
always @(*)
  begin 
    out = 0; // <-- initialize to zero
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 255 ; i=i+1 ) // Verilog doesn't allow decelerating 'i' here or '++'
      out = out + in[i];
  end
```

With SystemVerilog, it can be written as bellow. Modern Verilog simulations are SystemVerilog simulations. The preferred way to enable the feature is changing the file extension from .v to .sv

```
always_comb
  begin 
    out = '0; // <-- fill with zeros
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 255 ; i++ ) // or: foreach(in[i])
      out += in[i];
  end
```